# Swarm Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, ai, optimization

I have been asked to deliver a presentation for my university course on ant, bee and particle swarm algorithms. Therefore I am attempting to learn more about swarm algorithms and their uses within games. What I am looking for are presentations and articles which would help me to get a better grasp of the subject matter. As well as this video demonstrations of swarm algorithms used within games. Any help in finding relevant and up to date material would be appreciated.

Comment: Lookup *Flock algorithms* and *Flocking Behaviour*, which is the more common algorithmic term. There are some good Q&A on this site for them.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Pieter, I will do that. 

I am asking on here GameAlchemist as I thought the purpose of Stack Exchange was to share information regarding specific topics with those who have a greater understanding within that area. By commenting on here does not mean that I am not using other sources to find material.

Comment: Unfortunately, these kinds of vague, open-ended questions (and especially those [asking for references to external resources](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/639/is-asking-for-learning-resources-on-topic)) are not a very good fit for the Stack Exchange format. Please take a look at the [help/dont-ask] for more details. You might get some useful replies if you asked this in [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development), though (or, then again, you might not).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flocking behaviors is the way to go.  This [link](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-three-simple-rules-of-flocking-behaviors-alignment-cohesion-and-separation--gamedev-3444) gives a great explanation on how to code flocking in really any game engine.

Comment: The [Autonomous Agents chapter in Nature of Code](http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-6-autonomous-agents/) is also a really cool, clean treatment of the subject.

Comment: This link directs you to the article mentioned by Taras http://bit.ly/1kOI2ul